# React Native how to set launch sound

Tags: reactjs, audio, native

I just started react native and made 2 apps( they are similar but not same)
I can set launch screen to my app (with expo) in app.json but can't in real react native

How can I set a launch sound to my app, it will run once app opening(like 1-2 sec mp3)
Thank you